# is the sentence "leave alone to her" grammatically correct?

Tags: translation

I know the sentence "Leave her alone" is grammatically correct and common, but can you say "Leave alone to her"? It doesn't sound right but maybe it's grammatically correct?

I'm trying to translate a Spanish song into English and the most common sentence doesn't match the rhyme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sentence like 'Give her pizza.' can be transformed into 'Give pizza to her.' because 'her' is an indirect object and 'pizza' is a direct object. 'Leave her alone.' might look similar, but isn't, so the transformation rule doesn't apply. 'her' is the direct object, and 'alone' is an adjective complement. If rhyme is important for your translation, then you will have to find something else. Some translations of songs have to be very approximate.